# Finding all possible “lists” of possible pairs in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been thinking about a problem for the last few days but as I am a beginner in MATLAB, I have no clue how to solve it. Here is the background. Suppose that you have a symmetric `N×N` matrix where each element is either `0` or `1`, and `N = (1,2,...,n)`.

For example:

```
A =

    0     1     1     0

    1     0     0     1

    1     0     0     0

    0     1     0     0
```

If `A(i,j) == 1`, then it is possible to form the pair `(i,j)` and if `A(i,j)==0` then it is NOT possible to form the pair `(i,j)`. For example, `(1,2)` is a possible pair, as `A(1,2)==A(2,1)==1` but `(3,4)` is NOT a possible pair as `A(3,4)==A(4,3)==0`.

Here is the problem. Suppose that a member of the set `N` only can for a pair with at most one other distinct member of the set `N` (i.e., if 1 forms a pair with 2, then 1 cannot form a pair with 3). How can I find all possible “lists” of possible pairs? In the above example, one “list” would only consist of the pair `(1,2)`. If this pair is formed, then it is not possible to form any other pairs. Another “list” would be: `((1,3),(2,4))`. I have searched the forum and found that the latter “list” is the maximal matching that can be found, e.g., by using a bipartite graph approach. However, I am not necessarily only interested to find the maximal matching; I am interested in finding ALL possible “lists” of possible pairs. 
Another example:

```
A =

    0     1     1     1

    1     0     0     1

    1     0     0     0

    1     1     0     0
```

In this example, there are three possible lists:

```
   (1,2)
   ((1,3),(2,4))
   (1,4)
```

I hope that you can understand my question, and I apologize if am unclear. I appreciate all help I can get. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a fast approach.

**Code**

```
%// Given data, A
A =[ 0 1 1 1;
    1 0 0 1;
    1 0 0 0;
    1 1 0 0];

%%// The lists  will be stored in 'out' as a cell array and can be accessed as out{1}, out{2}, etc.
out = cell(size(A,1)-1,1);

%%// Code that detects the lists using "selective" diagonals
for k = 1:size(A,1)-1
    [x,y] = find(triu(A,k).*(~triu(ones(size(A)),k+1)));
    out(k) = {[x y]};
end
out(cellfun('isempty',out))=[]; %%// Remove empty lists

%%// Verification - Print out the lists
for k = 1:numel(out)
    disp(out{k})
end
```

**Output**

```
 1     2

 1     3
 2     4

 1     4
```

**EDIT 1**

Basically I will calculate all the the pairwise indices of the matrix to satisfy the criteria set in the question and then simply map them over the given matrix. The part of finding the "valid" indices is obviously the tedious part in it and in this code with some aggressive approach is expensive too when dealing with input matrices of sizes more than 10.

**Code**

```
%// Given data, A
A = [0 1 1 1; 1 0 1 1; 1 1 0 1; 1 1 1 0]

%%// Get all pairwise combinations starting with 1
all_combs = sortrows(perms(1:size(A,1)));
all_combs = all_combs(all_combs(:,1)==1,:);

%%// Get the "valid" indices
all_combs_diff = diff(all_combs,1,2);
valid_ind_mat = all_combs(all(all_combs_diff(:,1:2:end)>0,2),:);
valid_ind_mat = valid_ind_mat(all(diff(valid_ind_mat(:,1:2:end),1,2)>0,2),:);

%%// Map the ones of A onto the valid indices to get the lists in a matrix and then cell array
out_cell = mat2cell(valid_ind_mat,repmat(1,[1 size(valid_ind_mat,1)]),repmat(2,[1 size(valid_ind_mat,2)/2]));
A_masked = A(sub2ind(size(A),valid_ind_mat(:,1:2:end),valid_ind_mat(:,2:2:end)));
out_cell(~A_masked)={[]};

%%// Remove empty lists
out_cell(all(cellfun('isempty',out_cell),2),:)=[];

%%// Verification - Print out the lists
disp('Lists =');
for k1 = 1:size(out_cell,1)
    disp(strcat('  List',num2str(k1),':'));
    for k2 = 1:size(out_cell,2)
        if ~isempty(out_cell{k1,k2})
            disp(out_cell{k1,k2})
        end
    end
end
```

**Output**

```
A =

     0     1     1     1
     1     0     1     1
     1     1     0     1
     1     1     1     0

Lists =
  List1:
     1     2

     3     4

  List2:
     1     3

     2     4

  List3:
     1     4

     2     3
```

Comment: Thanks to both Rody Oldenhuis and Divakar for your fast replies! I have one question to Divakar:

If I try your solution for the matrix

A =    [0     1     1     1;
         1     0     1     1;
         1     1     0     1;
         1     1     1     0]

the output is 

ans =

     [1     2;
     2     3;
     3     4]


, ans =

     [1     3;
     2     4]


, ans =[

1 4],

In this case, however, the three possible “lists” are:

((1,2),(3,4)),
((1,3),(2,4)), and 
((1,4),(2,3))

Is there something I misunderstand in the output. Once again, many thanks.

Comment: @user3436833 and Rody, I might have mis-understood the whole thing! Coded up too soon maybe, let's see!

Comment: @user3436833 Got a question for you - Is it necessary to have those pairs into separate lists or can we have all those pairs in a Nx2 matrix?

Comment: @Divakar, I would prefer to have them as separate lists but if there is a nice way of generating these lists from the matrix, that will do the job as well. Thank.

Comment: @user3436833 This might be my last question for you - Let's suppose we have A as 6x6 of all `ones`, what would be the lists?

Comment: @Divakar, let me first clarify something I should have written before. The diagonal in the matrix is always zero as an element cannot form a pair with itself. Here are the lists in the 6x6 matrix (with zero diagonal): In this case, there are 15 different lists: ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6)),  ((1,2),(3,5),(4,6)), ((1,2),(3,6),(4,5)), ((1,3),(2,4),(5,6)), ((1,3),(2,5),(4,6)), ((1,3),(2,6),(4,5)),  ((1,4),(2,3),(5,6)), ((1,4),(2,5),(3,6)), ((1,4),(2,6),(3,4)), ((1,5),(2,3),(4,6)), ((1,5),(2,4),(3,6)),  ((1,5),(2,6),(3,4)), ((1,6),(2,3),(4,5)), ((1,6),(2,4),(3,5)), ((1,6),(2,5),(3,4)).

Comment: @user3436833 Check out the edited code! Been on this for sometime and finally I think it's done. Test it out!!

Comment: @divakar, thanks you so much! I really appreciate that you took time to hel out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a faster way to do it, but here's the obvious solution:

```
%// Set top half to 0, and find indices of all remaining 1's
A(triu(A)==1) = 0;
[ii,jj] = find(A);

%// Put these in a matrix for further processing
P = [ii jj];

%// Sort indices into 'lists' of the kind you defined 
X = repmat({}, size(P,1),1);
for ii = 1:size(P,1)-1
    X{ii}{1} = P(ii,:);
    for jj = ii+1:size(P,1)
        if ~any(ismember(P(ii,:), P(jj,:)))
            X{ii}{end+1} = P(jj,:); end
    end
end
```